# Numprint gobbles row-terminating command

Tags: tables, formatting

I use ctable for my tables, and I'd like to use numprint's autoformatting column types as well. Unfortunately, if the last column of the tabular is a numprint column, it breaks ctable's convenient macros for rules. The problem appears to be that the numprint column has to resort to some shenanigans to detect the end of a column.

This works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint}
\newcommand\foo{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{N{3}{0}}
    42 \\
    1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But this fails to compile with the error "! Misplaced \cr." and the code snippet accompanying it is: `` \reserved@c ->\ifnum 0=`{}\fi \cr ``

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint}
\newcommand\foo{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{N{3}{0}}
    42 \foo
    1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've tried looking at the numprint code, but I'm not clever enough to figure out how to solve this. Is there something I can do about this, or is it just not possible to make numprint work with other row terminators than `\\`?

Comment: You can use `\tabularnewline` instead of \\ to break the line, as in `\begin{tabular}{N{3}{0}}
    42 \tabularnewline
    1
\end{tabular}`.  I don't know if that would help `ctable` or not.

Comment: Use `\relax\foo` (or some other unexpandable macro like `\protect\foo`).

Comment: `\relax` before the terminator works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\relax\foo` (or some other unexpandable macro):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint}
\newcommand\foo{\\}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{N{3}{0}}
    42 \relax\foo
    1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```